# How to set a domain field as a list of numbers

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to define one field within the question_response table as a list of numbers.

```
@Entity
public class QuestionResponse {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="question_response_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long question_response_id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_uuid")
  private User users;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
  private Question questions;

  private List<Long> questionAns;
}
```

But it gave the error of:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: question_response, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(question_ans)]
```

I've also tried Set, but didn't work. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Could you try to put a `@Column` annotation for questionAns?

Comment: I realized that you may need create `an entity for questionAns` which contains `Long`, and define a `one-to-many relation` with `QuestionResponse`.

Comment: How are you thinking of storing that field? In a table ? http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_nonpc_join  or using an `AttributeConverter` into a column ? http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_nonpc_converter

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
public class Answer{
 @Column(name="id_response")
 private long Idresponse;
 @Column(name="response") 
 private String response;

@JsonIgnore  
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="question")
private QuestionResponse questionResponse;


 }
```

then in QuestionResponse class you can you use OneToMany relation as shown , it will work :

```
   @Entity
   public class QuestionResponse {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name="question_response_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
   private Long question_response_id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_uuid")
   private User users;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
   private Question questions;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "answer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
   private Set<Answer> answer;




   }
```